# $(...).carousel is not a function

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am implementing slide show of text with the carousel bootstrap and jQuery.
My Code is look like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-
             scale=1">      
<!--JQuery File -->
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <!--Logo of website -->
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="image/logo.jpg">

<!-- BootStrap CSS File-->
            <link href="lib/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Bootstrap JS File-->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/bootstrap.min.js">
            </script>

<!-- Custome CSS-->
            <link href="lib\css\custome.css"  rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- FA Icons -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:'Controller.php?user-tweet=true',
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(result){
                    var html_data = '';
                    var i = 0;
                    $.each(result['data'],function(index,data){
                        $('<div class="item"><p>"'+data['text']+'"</p></div>').appendTo('carousel-inner');
                        $('<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="'+i+'"></li>').appendTo('carousel-inndicators');
                        i++;
                    });
                    $('.item').first().addClass('active');
                    $('carousel-inndicators > li').first().addClass('active');
                    $('#carousel-example-generic').carousel({
                        interval:3000
                    });
                },
                failure: function(){
                    alert(Error);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
           <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators-->
            <ol class="carousel-inndicators">

            </ol>
            <!--Wrapper item -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <!-- Controlls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above code i got an error as

Uncaught TypeError:

```
$(...).carousel is not a function
at Object.success (home.php:42)
at i (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at A (jquery.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

is there any suggestion what i can do further so i can start my carousel successfully.

Infromation about Controller.php?user-tweet=true;
it gives me an array data object with the form of JSON once user is logged in. data object contains two fill. data['text'] and data['image']. Here i am texting with text in carousel. but i got above error.

Comment: That carousel is not a builtin feature but a third-party plugin, isn't it?

Comment: did you added carousle js library? I didn't see it in your code?

Comment: Where is your bootstrap script? NVM I see it now. But it's commented out weirdly.

Comment: it is feature of bootstrap

Comment: <!-- Bootstrap JS File-- > has a space between -- and > commenting out your script

Comment: @AlivetoDie which library you are talking about i am include bootstrap.min.js. Doesn't contains feature of carousel ?

Comment: @AlivetoDie The bootstrap js file does include a `carousel` function.

Comment: @Gezzasa i un-comment/update it. Please check it now my input.

Comment: Do you see any other errors in your browser console?

Comment: @DavidG no only Uncaught TypeError: which i mention in my question.

Comment: try using the CDN library to test with. maybe the package you are using has errors within itself?

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: Try replacing bootstrap.min.js tagging with **<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>**

Comment: @SchalkKeun can you give me reference of CDN ? i am not aware about it.

Comment: @DhiralKaniya . here you go with CDN link https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Comment: Replace you bootstrap include script with this:
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, so it must be the reference to the libraries. One big problem you have is that `lib/js/bootstrap.min.js` is a relative path so it will break if your URL has a subfolder in it. Try `/lib/js/bootstrap.min.js` for example. Make sure you are not getting a 404 error for any of your files.

Comment: @SchalkKeun it still give me same error.

Comment: for the reference i am hosting my code on free domain. You can also check it out reference link :- https://rtdemo.000webhostapp.com/home.php

Comment: OK. the issue is, your comment code you have there is killing the inclussion of the script. replace with the following:
`<!-- Bootstrap JS File -->`

Comment: @SchalkKeun i make change in comment but now it gives me an error as bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined

Comment: @SchalkKeun i got my mistakes. There are some typo mistakes in my jQuery. Thanks for help me out.

Comment: @DavidG i got my mistakes. There are some typo mistakes in my jQuery. Thanks for help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were some error in the ajax function in appendTo function. In that function i didn't notice that carousel-indicators is my class or id.

so updated ajax code is...

```
       $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:'Controller.php?user-tweet=true',
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(result){
                    var html_data = '';
                    var i = 0;
                    $.each(result['data'],function(index,data){
                        console.log(data);
                        $('<div class="item"><p>"'+data['text']+'"</p></div>').appendTo('.carousel-inner');
                        $('<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="'+i+'"></li>').appendTo('.carousel-indicators');
                        i++;
                    });
                    $('.item').first().addClass('active');
                    $('.carousel-indicators > li').first().addClass('active');
                    $('#carousel-example-generic').carousel();
                },
                failure: function(){
                    alert(Error);
                }
            });
```

and there is one another mistake in code which we discussed in the comment with @SchalkKeun comment having extra space.Please be consider that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change this code 
`$('#carousel-example-generic').carousel({});` to 
   **`$('.carousel #carousel-example-generic').carousel({});`**

Check this...

Comment: I am sorry,  anyway  try this also, $('.carousel'). carousel();

Comment: Please check my answer in that i wrote where i made mistakes.